# Google App Script google doc to mail html

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send google doc content to email , but could not get it in html format, please help.

Mail is going through but it does not contain the font and colors.

Code Follows:

```
  function getGoogleDocumentAsHTML(){
  var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId() ;
  var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); //needed to get Drive Scope requested
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+id+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
method      : "get",
headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
muteHttpExceptions:true,

  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();

   var subject = "November 19 2015";
 MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", subject,"", {htmlBody:html, name:"Work Program", cc:"", replyTo:"xxxxx@gmail.com"});

}
```

Comment: Please share your code! Obviously something is missing but unless you share your work we cannot help you.

Comment: please see the edit ..

Comment: Right now the html is coming from the variable - have you tried sending the HTML straight through just to check if the issue is coming from somewhere in that variable? Is the only HTML in the email the fonts and colors (aka is some of the HTML working and some not)? I'd also try pasting the HTML into a text doc and opening it in a browser to see what happens.

Comment: yes i have tried that, also tried downloading the html and opening up in a browser, it renders properly in the browser .

Answer (score 0):

Add this....

body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }

Reason for this solution is explained [here](http://pixelcog.com/blog/2015/gmail-to-pdf/)

Comment: please post content of link here